# Can't add s3 notification for lambda using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I want to use boto3 to configure an s3 bucket to  invoke an AWS lambda every time an object is created in that bucket. Here is my code:

```
s3 = ..boto3 resource
bucket_notification = s3.BucketNotification(bucket_name)
lambda_arn = .. arn for lambda

response = bucket_notification.put(
   NotificationConfiguration={'LambdaFunctionConfigurations': [
      {
                'LambdaFunctionArn': lambda_arn,
                'Events': [
                    's3:ObjectCreated:*'
                ],

      },
]})
```

I get the error:

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidArgument)
>   when calling the PutBucketNotificationConfiguration operation: Unable
>   to validate the following destination configurations

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One has to add permissions on the lambda end to allow S3 to invoke the lambda function. Beware, if you manually create the event source mapping using the AWS Lambda GUI and then delete the event source mapping, the permission still exists! So you won't get the above error.

However, if you start from scratch and then try to add the notification, the above error will occur.

Permissions are added by:

```
 client = ...boto3 lambda client
 response = client.add_permission(
     FunctionName=lambda_name,
     StatementId='1',
     Action='lambda:InvokeFunction',
     Principal='s3.amazonaws.com',
     SourceArn=s3_arn,
     SourceAccount='66666666666'
 )
```

Comment: Thanks. This saved me a lot of headache. Also, if you are using CloudFormation to deploy your lambda function, then you can add the required permission straight from the template: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-permission.html

Comment: +1 for this. Ran into the same issue trying to add an s3 notification for an SQS queue; it started working after I added the right permissions/policy on the SQS end.

Comment: It hepls, also for some reason I needed to add a sleep delay between add_permission and put notification config.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue before -
You should definitely consider @RAbraham's answer on this question, but there is one more thing you might want to check;

Check if any of the events on your s3 bucket are orphans, i.e if a lambda function is deleted, you will have to delete the corresponding s3 event as well, if it exists. If you don't do that and try to add/edit any events on the same bucket, it will give you the same error.

If the lambda doesn't exist, it cannot update the entire bucket's notification configuration, irrespective of which event you're updating, as it is atomic ([aws-source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4bXR.png)) in nature.

reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-bucket-notification-configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

ANSIBLE SCRIPT:   Do not give spaces in 'event_name' value

```
---
- name: deploy lambda
   hosts: localhost
   connection: local
   gather_facts: false 

tasks:
 - name: add lambda event notification for a bucket
     s3_bucket_notification:
       state: present
       event_name: Test1_lambda_Event_name
       bucket_name: test-private
       lambda_function_arn: arn:aws-us-xxxxxlambda
       events: ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]
       prefix: Test_R/configuration      
     register: output 
     ignore_errors: true
     
   - name: debug output
     debug:
       msg: "output is: {{output}}"
```